# What to use for starting working with java persistence in Eclipse?

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

I need to use JPA in a project. I have no previous experience with JPA and what I am reading through internet sources is a little confusing. I do not know if I should use Hibernate, EclipseLink or some other.

What can you recommend for me as a beginner?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Refer this [hibernate-and-mysql](http://devbank.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/jpa-stand-alone-project-with-hibernate-and-mysql/)

Comment: your welcome by the way you should also try to search your self it will increase your search capability and you will learn different things also.

Comment: Yes I searched but I needed an opinion on which suits better for me as a beginner

Comment: @AyazAliKhatri: Any particular reason that you cannot merge all your answers in a single one? This is not a lottery - one submission is quite enough...

Comment: @thkala tahnsk for telling that its not lottery